# BeautifulSoup extracting Data from table but when field is empty it doesnt notice it

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a project where I need to extract the ingredients of recipes into a CSV file. I already have my code but the problem is there are some recipes like [this](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1521151257327860/Schneemoussetorte-mit-Rhabarber.html) where are many empty quantities. But my program doesn't notice it and so everything moves "down". I hope you can help me. This is what I already have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

urls = ['https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1521151257327860/Schneemoussetorte-mit-Rhabarber.html']
amount = []
ingredients = []
ids = []
all_data = []

for url, id2 in zip(urls, range(len(urls))):
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    for tag in soup2.select('.recipe-ingredients h3,.td-left'):
        if tag.name == 'h3':
            amount.append(" ")
            ids.append(id2)
        else:
            try:
                amount.append([re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', str(tag.find('a').contents))])
                ids.append(id2)
            except AttributeError:
                try:
                    amount.append([re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', str(tag.find('span').contents))])
                    ids.append(id2)
                except:
                    continue

    for tag in soup2.select('.recipe-ingredients h3,.td-right'):
        if tag.name == 'h3':
            ingredients.append([tag.get_text(strip=True)])
        else:
            try:
                ingredients.append([re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', str(tag.find('a').contents))])

            except AttributeError:
                ingredients.append([re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', str(tag.find('span').contents))])
for i in range(len(ingredients)):
    try:
        all_data.append([ids[i], ingredients[i], amount[i]])
    except IndexError:
        all_data.append(ingredients[i])
```

URLs is normally a list with many URLs but to test the one should be enough. In the first big for-loop, I try to extract the data I need(id,ingredients, amount) and in the second small for-loop I just put it into a list so I can easily put this into a CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script loads all data into list of 3-element tuples (1. is ID, 2. is amount, 3. is ingredient):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pprint import pprint


urls = ['https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1521151257327860/Schneemoussetorte-mit-Rhabarber.html',
        'https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/2557531400251892/Rhabarber-Streusel-Kuchen.html']
all_data = []

current_id = ''
for url, id2 in zip(urls, range(len(urls))):
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    for tag in soup2.select('.recipe-ingredients h3, .ingredients tr:has(td)'):
        if tag.name == 'h3':
            current_id = tag.get_text(strip=True)
        else:
            all_data.append([current_id, *[re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', td.get_text(strip=True)) for td in tag.select('td')]])

    print(url)
    print('-' * 80)
    pprint(all_data)
    print()
    all_data = []
```

Prints:

```
https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1521151257327860/Schneemoussetorte-mit-Rhabarber.html
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[['', '', 'Fett für die Form'],
 ['', '4', 'Ei(er)'],
 ['', '125 g', 'Butter'],
 ['', '325 g', 'Zucker und 4-5 EL extra'],
 ['', '', 'Salz'],
 ['', '3 Pck.', 'Vanillezucker'],
 ['', '150 g', 'Mehl'],
 ['', '2 TL, gestr.', 'Backpulver'],
 ['', '5 EL', 'Milch'],
 ['', '4 EL', 'Mandelblättchen'],
 ['', '500 g', 'Rhabarber'],
 ['', '1 Pck.', 'Puddingpulver . (Vanille)'],
 ['', '400 ml', 'Sahne'],
 ['', '', 'Puderzucker zum Bestäuben']]

https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/2557531400251892/Rhabarber-Streusel-Kuchen.html
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[['', '700 g', 'Rhabarber'],
 ['Für die Streusel:', '100 g', 'Butter, flüssig'],
 ['Für die Streusel:', '200 g', 'Mehl'],
 ['Für die Streusel:', '1 Prise(n)', 'Salz'],
 ['Für die Streusel:', '60 g', 'Puderzucker'],
 ['Für die Streusel:', '1 Pck.', 'Vanillezucker'],
 ['Für den Teig:', '225 g', 'Butter, weiche'],
 ['Für den Teig:', '225 g', 'Zucker'],
 ['Für den Teig:', '1 Prise(n)', 'Salz'],
 ['Für den Teig:', '3', 'Ei(er), Größe M'],
 ['Für den Teig:', '275 g', 'Mehl'],
 ['Für den Teig:', '2 TL, gestr.', 'Backpulver'],
 ['Für den Teig:', '150 g', 'Naturjoghurt']]
```

Comment: Thank you. And this works because it goes through every tr tag that has a td tag in it and than it sometimes finds something and sometimes not? And where can I see that its a tuple and not a array the *?

Comment: @Frederick It always find something (`<h3>` or `<tr>` tags). When you look at the HTML of the page, you will see, that there are empty `<td>` tags in places where there isn't any ingredient. That's where empty strings `''` come from.